# Is a port channel necessary between redundant core switches?

Tags: design, etherchannel

A course I am following mentions some examples and basics of network design, which includes the 2-tier/3-tier campus LAN designs.

About the 3-tier design
[image]

Would a port channel be necessary between C1 and C2? Why would we want to configure it there at all? I can't imagine when user traffic would ever pass through that port channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would a port channel be necessary between C1 and C2?

Not always. The point is to provide sufficient bandwidth between the cores plus you don't want that link to fail.

> Why would we want to configure it there at all?

A redundant link requires at least two physical links.

> I can't imagine when user traffic would ever pass through that port channel.

That depends on the actual design. If your cores run active/passive (with L2 mostly) then just management traffic passes there, but if you design a proper L3 mesh you run them active/active and *a lot* of traffic is to be expected.